# How to slice a circular list iteratively ? (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, slice, modulo

I am slicing a list of objects in a loop but can't seem to make the slicing wrap around the ends of that list even with modulo indexing:

```
N = 4
nums = range(N) # [0, 1, 2, 3]

for i in xrange(N):
    print nums[i: (i+2)%N]
```

prints:

```
[0, 1]
[1, 2]
[]
[]
```

How can I make it so it returns:

```
[0, 1]
[1, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 0]
```

note: I am using Python 2.7 and can't import modules like numpy

Comment: The only slice notation that would return `[3, 0]` from that list requires the step argument: `nums[3::-3]`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a "true" circular pair of numbers, you should incorporate some [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice, izip

circ_list = izip(cycle(nums), islice(cycle(nums), 1, None))
```

This is an endless iterator which will keep yielding the kinds of number pairs you want.

`cycle(nums)` will endlessly repeat your list of numbers, `islice(..., 1, None)` skips the first item of it, so you essentially have `[0, 1, 2, ...]` and `[1, 2, 3, ...]`, which `izip` combines.

You can now for example take a small slice of it:

```
>>> list(islice(circ_list, 5))
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 0), (0, 1)]
```

Comment: Thank you. So far this is the only answer correctly addressing the slicing part.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do :

```py
N = 4
nums = range(N)

for i in xrange(N):
    print [nums[i], nums[(i+1)%N]]
```

```py
[0, 1]
[1, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try using:

```
N = 4
nums = xrange(N)

for i in xrange(N):
    print (nums[i:(i+2)%(i+N)] + [0] * 2)[:2]
```